# why ArangoDB graph query too slow?

Tags: arangodb

Hi I'm newbie in ArangoDB.

In my case, below there are collections.

- broadcast (24,518 doc)
- videoGroup (5,699 doc)
- episode (124,893 doc)
- videoClip (485,878 doc)
- character (55,541 doc)

And Their collections has relation each other, below

- broadcast has many videoGroup(1:n), so I create broadcastToVideoGroup Edge Collection
- broadcast has many character(1:n), so I create broadcastToCharacter Edge Collection
- videoGroup has many episode(1:n), so I create videoGroupToEpisode EdgeCollection
- episode has many videoClip(1:n), so I create episodeToVideoClip EdgeCollection

So I want all broadcast join all collection like below query.

```
 FOR b IN broadcast
    return MERGE(b, {

        character : (
            FOR c IN 1..1 OUTBOUND b._id broadcastToCharacter
                return c
        ),
        videoGroup : (
            FOR s IN 1..1 OUTBOUND b._id broadcastToVideoGroup
                return merge(s, {
                    episodes : (
                        FOR e IN 1..1 OUTBOUND s._id videoGroupToEpisode
                            return merge(e, {
                                clips : (
                                    FOR c IN 1..1 OUTBOUND e._id episodeToClip
                                        return c
                                )
                            })
                    )
                })
        )
    })
```

I expect joining all data to broadcast, like below

```
[{
  title : "office season3",
  // and some other broadcast properties

  character : [{
    "role" : "Dwight", ...
  },...],
  videoGroup : [{
    groupId : 123,
    // and some other videoGroup properties

    episodes : [{
       episodeName : "Ep01. foobar",
       // and some other episode properties

       clips : [{
         clipName : "First Season foobar!",
         // and some other clip properties
       }, ...]
    }, ...]
  },...]
},...]
```

but query too slow, execution time over 10sec. below is my explain above query.
Query string:

```
  FOR b IN broadcast return MERGE(b, {character : (FOR c IN 1..1 OUTBOUND b._id broadcastToCharacter return 
 c),videoGroup : (FOR s IN 1..1 OUTBOUND b._id broadcastToVideoGroup return merge(s, {episodes : (FOR e IN 1..1 
 OUTBOUND s._id videoGroupToEpisode return merge(e, { clips : ...

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType                   Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode                 1   * ROOT
  2   EnumerateCollectionNode   24518     - FOR b IN broadcast   /* full collection scan */
  7   SubqueryNode              24518       - LET #2 = ...   /* subquery */
  3   SingletonNode                 1         * ROOT
  4   CalculationNode               1           - LET #13 = b.`_id`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: b : broadcast */
  5   TraversalNode                 5           - FOR c  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND #13 /* startnode */  broadcastToCharacter
  6   ReturnNode                    5           - RETURN c
 24   SubqueryNode              24518       - LET #11 = ...   /* subquery */
  8   SingletonNode                 1         * ROOT
  9   CalculationNode               1           - LET #17 = b.`_id`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: b : broadcast */
 10   TraversalNode                 1           - FOR s  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND #17 /* startnode */  broadcastToVideoGroup
 21   SubqueryNode                  1           - LET #9 = ...   /* subquery */
 11   SingletonNode                 1             * ROOT
 12   CalculationNode               1               - LET #21 = s.`_id`   /* attribute expression */
 13   TraversalNode                25               - FOR e  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND #21 /* startnode */  videoGroupToEpisode
 18   SubqueryNode                 25               - LET #7 = ...   /* subquery */
 14   SingletonNode                 1                 * ROOT
 15   CalculationNode               1                   - LET #25 = e.`_id`   /* attribute expression */
 16   TraversalNode                 8                   - FOR c  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND #25 /* startnode */  episodeToClip
 17   ReturnNode                    8                   - RETURN c
 19   CalculationNode              25               - LET #29 = MERGE(e, { "clips" : #7 })   /* simple expression */
 20   ReturnNode                   25               - RETURN #29
 22   CalculationNode               1           - LET #31 = MERGE(s, { "episodes" : #9 })   /* simple expression */
 23   ReturnNode                    1           - RETURN #31
 25   CalculationNode           24518       - LET #33 = MERGE(b, { "character" : #2, "videoGroup" : #11 })   /* simple expression */   /* collections used: b : broadcast */
 26   ReturnNode                24518       - RETURN #33

Indexes used:
 By   Type   Collection        Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields        Ranges
  5   edge   broadcastToCharacter     false    false        19.42 %   [ `_from` ]   base OUTBOUND
 10   edge   broadcastToVideoGroup        false    false        90.89 %   [ `_from` ]   base OUTBOUND
 13   edge   videoGroupToEpisode   false    false         3.99 %   [ `_from` ]   base OUTBOUND
 16   edge   episodeToClip     false    false        11.55 %   [ `_from` ]   base OUTBOUND

Traversals on graphs:
 Id   Depth   Vertex collections   Edge collections   Options                                   Filter conditions
  5   1..1                         broadcastToCharacter      uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path   
 10   1..1                         broadcastToVideoGroup         uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path   
 13   1..1                         videoGroupToEpisode    uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path   
 16   1..1                         episodeToClip      uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path   

Optimization rules applied:
 none
```